# How can I fix redeclared warning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
x = [[] for i in range(5)]
y = [[] for i in range(10)]
```

> Redeclared 'i' defined above without usage

How can I fix this warning?!!!

Comment: Usually this means you already use `i` somewhere in that function. It is not wrong, but it can be dangerous, since most people think that (in Python-2.7) these variable is scoped locally, it is not.

Comment: Many linters will silence if you use _ instead of i (_ makes it explicit that it is a throw away variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a warning since in Python-2.x, the variables in *list comprehension* are "leaking". It means that these are *not* locally scoped. For instance:

```
>>> i = 'somevalue'
>>> [[] for i in range(5)]
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> i
4
```

Since you use `i` in both list comprehensions, you thus overwrite the `i` declared in the first one, with the `i` of the second one.

If you want to get rid of this error, you can use different variable names:

```
x = [[] for i in range(5)]
y = [[] for j in range(10)]
```

In this case you however do not make use of `i` and `j` in the list comprehension. Usually a "throwaway" variable is the underscore (`_`) or even double underscore (`__`):

```
x = [[] for __ in range(5)]
y = [[] for __ in range(10)]
```

As is written in the ["*Hitchhikers guide to Python*"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#create-an-ignored-variable):

> If you need to assign something (for instance, in Unpacking) but will not need that variable, use `__`
>   (..)
>
> > Many Python style guides **recommend the use of a single underscore
> >     `_` for throwaway variables** rather than the double underscore `__`
> >     recommended here. The issue is that `_` is commonly used as an alias
> >     for the `gettext()` function, and is also used at the interactive
> >     prompt to hold the value of the last operation. Using a double
> >     underscore instead is just as clear and almost as convenient, and
> >     eliminates the risk of accidentally interfering with either of these
> >     other use cases.

Comment: Is `_` officially declared as such, or is it a mere convention (which, as commented elsewhere, is followed by "many linters" for convenience only)?

Comment: @usr2564301: well the Hitchhikers guide to Python recommends two underscores. These is especially useful since libraries like Django use `_` for `gettext()` (to make translations). That being said if you use an interactive session, the underscore will usually take the output of the last function call.